# C#: List of functions with variable number of arguments

Tags: c#, function

Is it possible in C# to have higher-order function which takes a function with an arbitrary number and type of arguments and return values, e.g.,

```
// No valid C# code
void MyFunction(Func f)
{
    // do something
}
MyFunction(string.Join);      // type: Func<String, IEnumerable<String>, String>
MyFunction(string.CompareTo); // type: Func<object, int>
// ...
```

I guess, this question really boils down to whether there's a most generic type for functions which can hold any function with possibly different number and type of arguments.

My use-case is the following: I have a method which takes a `MethodInfo` object. Currently, I do something like

```
DoSomething(((Func<object, int>)string.CompareTo).Method)
```

However, I'd have to repeat this for every different kind of function I expect. I'd prefer a solution in which `DoSomething` could by itself determine the type, so I just give it the Function itself instead of the `MethodInfo` object.

EDIT:

To be more precise, I'm writing a Linq-To-X provider using ReLinq. I got some example code from a tutorial blog on this topic (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42059/re-linq-ishing-the-Pain-Using-re-linq-to-Implement and https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-linq-to-sql-10-implementing-linq-to-sql-provider). For eager execution functions like `Sum` or `Count`, I need to wrap them into a `MethodCallExpression` object.

In the example code, it is solved like this:

```
public static IQuery CountToSql<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
{
    ArgumentChecker.CheckNull(source, nameof(source));
     var expression =
        Expression.Call(
            null,
            GetMethodInfo(Queryable.Count, source),
            new Expression[] { source.Expression }
            );
     return ToQuery(expression, ((DbQueryable<T>)source).SyntaxProvider);
}

private static MethodInfo GetMethodInfo<T1, T2>(Func<T1, T2> f, T1 unused1 => f.Method;

private static MethodInfo GetMethodInfo<T1, T2, T3>(Func<T1, T2, T3> f, T1 unused1, T2 unused2) => f.Method;

// ...
```

However, I don't want to write this for every type of function (e.g., `Queryable.Sum`, `Queryable.Count`, ...). The current solution necessitates it. I just want one single method that can handle all, as they look the same for 90%.

Comment: This feels like a XY problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. **Why** are you trying to do this?

Comment: But **why** @Sweeper? What is it ultimately doing to be used for? Because, perhaps, knowing that context will open up an alternative approach which will better serve their needs.

Comment: Though I am quite not clear on your question, but 'dynamic' type would be helpful in any way?

Comment: Your question is unclear, you're mixing instance methods with static methods, additionally, `string.Join` has 5 overloads, which one do you want to pass in? `string.CompareTo` has 2 overloads. Either way, there's no way to get a MethodInfo without explicitly asking for it, there's no way to get the simple syntax you're asking for.

Comment: dynamic type is not so "dynamic". .net creates a specific data types for each call. And it's not always works as it sxpected. I think this is not solve problem.

Comment: Ok, to add more context: I'm writing a Linq-To-X provider using ReLinq. For queries like `table.Sum()`, I have to wrap it into an MethodCallExpression before I pass it to my QueryModelVisitor. However, I don't want to write a single method for each function (`Count`, `Take`, ...), but rather have one method that can handle all.

Answer (score 0):

It seem strange that you need to call such different delegates from one place.

I think you need something like "EventDispatcher", when your code got data that should be then casted to object, but after that inside a call you want to operate a real objects.

If I wrong please tell more about task.

If I right, you have to replace reflections by generics. Create method that will wrap you delegate by Action.

```
    public Action<object> WrapCall<T, K>( Func<T, K> func)
    {
        return (data) => func((T)data);
    }

    public Action<object, object> WrapCall<T1, T2, K>(Func<T1, T2,K> func)
    {
        return (t1Data, t2Data) => func((T1)t1Data, (T2)t2Data);
    }
```

and so one.

It may be not solve your problem but will helps you to find solution in other way.